# Can I use Spring JPA with a read only database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, jdbc

I'm doing a programming exercise tomorrow where I will have to pull data from a database and display it as a table on a web page using the Spring framework. My Initial thought was to use the Spring JPA for accessing the MySQL database, but I have since learned that the database will be read only.

Would this mean the Spring JPA would give errors when trying to connect? Is the best option in this situation to use regular JDBC functionality?

Many thanks

Comment: *Would this mean the Spring JPA would give errors when trying to connect?* No. JPA won't insert, update or delete anything unless you ask it to. Why would anyone want that?

Comment: As long as the user you're connection to the database has read abilities then spring jpa will work fine. Only time you're going to run into errors if i you try to do any inserts or updates.